# Remove Event Listeners on Array of Elements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove event listeners on group of elements once specific class is added to the parent. Once I click on enable editing and hover over some element that element gets selected. I want to be able disable selecting elements once I click on disable editing button. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/chille1987/a1d3gb7u/15/

HTML

```
<button class="enable-editing">Enable Editing</button>
<button class="disable-editing">Disable Editing</button>

<div id="editor">
    <p>This is first paragraph</p>
    <p>This is second paragraph</p>
    <h1>This is heading 1</h1>
    <p class="empty-paragraph"><br /></p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <h2>This is heading 2</h2>
    <p>Another paragraph goes here</p>
    <h3>H3 heading goes here</h3>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
const enable = document.querySelector('.enable-editing');
const disable = document.querySelector('.disable-editing');
const editor = document.querySelector('#editor');
let target;

enable.addEventListener('click', () => {
    editor.classList.add('editing-enabled')
    let allElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.editing-enabled *'));
    allElements.forEach(child => {
        child.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            target = e.target;
            selectText(target);
        })
    })
})

disable.addEventListener('click', () => {
    editor.classList.remove('editing-enabled')
})

function selectText(node) {
    node = node;
    if (document.body.createTextRange) {
        const range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(node);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        const selection = window.getSelection();
        const range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(node);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    } else {
        console.warn("Could not select text in node: Unsupported browser.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean removeEventListener?

Comment: @JerryJoseph Yes, removeEventListener once editing-enabled class is removed from parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few changes:

```js
const enable = document.querySelector('.enable-editing');
const disable = document.querySelector('.disable-editing');
const editor = document.querySelector('#editor');
let target;

const listener = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  target = e.target;
  selectText(target);
}

enable.addEventListener('click', () => {
  editor.classList.add('editing-enabled')
  let allElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.editing-enabled *'));
  allElements.forEach(child => {
    child.addEventListener('mouseenter', listener)
  })
})

disable.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let allElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.editing-enabled *'));
  allElements.forEach(child => {
    child.removeEventListener('mouseenter', listener, {
      passive: true
    })
  })
  editor.classList.remove('editing-enabled')
})

function selectText(node) {
  node = node;
  if (document.body.createTextRange) {
    const range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(node);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(node);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  } else {
    console.warn("Could not select text in node: Unsupported browser.");
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="enable-editing">Enable Editing</button>
<button class="disable-editing">Disable Editing</button>

<div id="editor">
    <p>This is first paragraph</p>
    <p>This is second paragraph</p>
    <h1>This is heading 1</h1>
    <p class="empty-paragraph"><br /></p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <h2>This is heading 2</h2>
    <p>Another paragraph goes here</p>
    <h3>H3 heading goes here</h3>
</div>
```

There are more options you can use here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener